# Allow others on shared drive to use access odbc connection

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc

I have an Access file with ADD and UPDATE queries that is linked to an SQL database of some sort (Orderwise). I'm building the reports and things, but someone else in our company will end up using it - possibly a variety of people - therefore I've put it on a Shared Drive.

However, when I access it from another computer (tried to demonstrate it to the Ops manager) it loses the connection to the SQL database, despite both computers having access to that drive too. I'm new to this but I think the ODBC file / connection it relies on is somewhere in the computer that built the database - the error message is `ODBC connection to 'Orderwise 2' failed.`.

I've tried researching it but haven't found anything very conclusive, it seems to involve .mdb files but I don't know where those are, and hunting through the control panel settings thing doesn't give an option to move the odbc to a shared drive.

How can I share this database so everyone on the shared drive can use the live data connection?

Comment: You have to configure same `ODBC` to other computer. Or you have to re-design database to execute `INSERT`, `UPDATE` commands by `VBA` to your `SQL` database. Then you no need to configure `ODBC` to each computer. Creating `Pass-Through` query by `VBA` will help to run report.

Comment: @Harun24HR Ok, thanks for that. Can the ODBC be copied, or does it have to be made from scratch? The Orderwise database has a password on it, so I'm not sure the other things you mentioned would work.

Comment: ODBC have to made from scratch. Other thing will work. You have to provide paswword in connection string to `VBA` coding.

Comment: Thanks so much @Harun24HR. One final question; if I want to do the VBA thing you recommended, what should I google to get started? I know VBA for excel a fair bit but don't know what commands that particular task would use.

Comment: I have codes to connect SQL Database by VBA and run commands like INSERT, DETELE, UPDATE and so on. I will give tomorrow as now I am writing this comment from my mobile phone.

Comment: Have a look on this article [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/create-dsn-less-connection-linkted-table)

Comment: [Another good article here.](http://www.accessmvp.com/DJSteele/DSNLessLinks.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is code to connect SQL Database and run commands.

```
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
'Add reference Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library
'Fix SQL Server Connection ERROR! See below link
'https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/
    
    'Declare variables'
        Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
        Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

        Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
        Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
        
        Dim strEmpID As String, strEmpName As String
        Dim JoiningDate As Date
        Dim eSalary As Integer
        Dim myRate As Double

    'Open Connection'
        objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=192.168.0.150;User ID=sa;Password=saDBpassword;"
        objMyConn.Open

    'Another provider
    'Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=192.168.0.150,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=pubs;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
        Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
        
        ' Insert data to SQL Database table.
        
        strEmpID = InputBox("Enter Employee ID:", "Employee ID", "HO-300")
        strEmpName = InputBox("Enter Employee Name:", "Employee Name", "Mr. SQL")
        JoiningDate = InputBox("Enter Joining Date:", "Joining Date", Date)
        eSalary = InputBox("Enter Salary:", "Salary", 10000)
        myRate = InputBox("Enter Rate:", "Rate", 11.11)
        
        objMyCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [TestDB].[dbo].[tblEmpInfo] (EmpID, EmpName, jDate, Salary, HourRate) Values('" _
                                & strEmpID & "', '" _
                                & strEmpName & "', '" _
                                & JoiningDate & "', " _
                                & eSalary & ", " _
                                & myRate & ")"
                                
        
        objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        objMyCmd.Execute 'Execute SQL command

End Sub
```

You have to add `ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library` to reference. I am using `MS-Access-2013`. Object reference may varies depending on MS-Access versions.

[image]

Please read this article carefully to troubleshoot network service barrier. [SQL Server Fix Error.](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)